# Как организовать автозапрос данных страницы на Javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте. Я делаю социальную сеть и сейчас мне нужно создать механизм обновления списка приватных сообщений в разговоре. То есть, чтобы они обновлялись на лету. Я понимаю, что можно сделать просто каждые десять секунд повторение ajax запроса, но кажется, что я когда-то читал о способе, который каким-то образом держит соединение открытым. Что это за способ?  Возможно я ошибаюсь и такого способа не существует, в таком случае, не ругайтесь пожалуйста:)

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Похоже это то что я искал. Скажите ещё, какая кроссбраузерность в этого решения и какие минусы, если можно?

Comment: Похоже, что я все таки читал про websockets доступный в html 5. Этот метод не работает в ослике версии ниже 10, но зато проще в использовании.

Comment: мб socket.io?

Comment: Это ещё прикольнее. Но пока ограничусь websockets ведь это проект ради забавы и необходимости кроссбраузерности нет.